# Get the latest value of one field while grouping on others

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to 'roll up' large batches of transactions into more manageable, pointed rows of data. For instance:

```
ID        item        description     qty      unitPrice    extPrice
1234      foo         foo bar          6       10            60
2345      foo         foo bar          2       10            20
3456      foo         foo bar          2       15            30
```

Would be grouped into another table as:

```
ID        item        description     qty      extPrice     lastPricePaid
1         foo         foo bar          10      110          15
```

The thing I'm currently having trouble with is figuring out how to determine that `lastPricePaid` value. Here's the current query *without* that included:

```
SELECT id, groupId, datePurchase, vendor, venItem, item, itemDesc, uom, SUM(qtyPurchase) AS `qtyPurchase`, SUM(extPrice) AS `totalPrice`, MAX(unitPrice) AS `maxPrice`, unitPrice, code, stripped_venitem, MAX(datePurchase) as `maxDate`, SUM(extPrice) as `extPrice`, PONum
FROM transactions t
WHERE (((qtyPurchase)!=0))
GROUP BY groupId, vendor, venItem, item, itemDesc, uom
HAVING datePurchase > (MAX(datePurchase) - DATE_SUB(MAX(datePurchase), INTERVAL 1 YEAR));
```

The real trick is that since I'm pulling into Solr I need to get this into a single query without relying on processing tricks after the fact.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't test it but, have you tried ordering by id? This way you should get the unitPrice related to the one with greater id.

```
SELECT id, groupId, datePurchase, vendor, venItem, item, itemDesc, uom, SUM(qtyPurchase) AS `qtyPurchase`, SUM(extPrice) AS `totalPrice`, MAX(unitPrice) AS `maxPrice`, unitPrice, code, stripped_venitem, MAX(datePurchase) as `maxDate`, SUM(extPrice) as `extPrice`, PONum, unitPrice as lastPricePaid
FROM transactions t
WHERE (((qtyPurchase)!=0))
GROUP BY groupId, vendor, venItem, item, itemDesc, uom
HAVING datePurchase > (MAX(datePurchase) - DATE_SUB(MAX(datePurchase), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
order by id desc
```

Comment: This is getting close. it is, however, grabbing the *first* unitPrice it finds. I've attempted a few variations such as changing the `ORDER BY` direction as well as the field being ordered on.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, have you tried androi solution? Also, I can't do it now but if you can prepare a sql fiddle so we can play with it until reach a solution

Comment: Ended up getting it with a really nasty `SELECT` within the initial `SELECT` :\ Like so: `SELECT id, groupId, ...(SELECT unitPrice FROM transactions tt WHERE t.facilityId = tt.facilityId AND t.venItem = tt.venItem AND t.facItem = tt.facItem AND t.uom = tt.uom AND t.facDesc = tt.facDesc AND t.vendor = tt.vendor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as lastPricePaid`

Comment: Not enough to notice or matter. Since it's just something that's done to feed into Solr it doesn't have to be too performant :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but thats works for me:

```
SELECT t.id, t.groupId, t.datePurchase, t.vendor, t.venItem, t.item,
 t.itemDesc, t.uom, SUM(t.qtyPurchase) AS `qtyPurchase`, 
SUM(t.extPrice) AS `totalPrice`, MAX(t.unitPrice) AS `maxPrice`,
t.unitPrice, t.code, t.stripped_venitem,
MAX(t.datePurchase) as `maxDate`, SUM(t.extPrice) as `extPrice`, t.PONum , 
t1.unitPrice as 'lastPricePaid'
FROM transactions t, transactions t1
WHERE (((t.qtyPurchase)!=0)) 
AND t1.id = (
      SELECT max(t2.id) FROM transactions t2
)
GROUP BY t.groupId, t.vendor, t.venItem, t.item, t.itemDesc, t.uom
HAVING t.datePurchase > (MAX(t.datePurchase) - DATE_SUB(MAX(t.datePurchase), INTERVAL 1 YEAR));
```